# How to create an immobile continent?

Tags: magic, geography, tectonics, erosion

For my fantasy world, there is an artificially created continent (created by magic, but an important note is that the continent itself is ENTIRELY non-magical.)

The continent is nearly 20,000 years old, but I don't want the coastline, location, or other things to change naturally, although it should still be able to be shaped by human hands.

The continent itself is NOT on a normal continental plate, it is a massive island on top of a ocean plate, and it is next to a mid-ocean ridge.

How can I make the continent immobile?

Comment: if the continent has been created by magic perhaps the creator, has added some kind of magical anchor to the whole continent directly linked by magical mean to a fix point in the planet since it's magic the anchor point don't really need to be real/tangible (it could be interesting if the BBEG  evil plan was to sever this magical link and let the contient drift)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with 'immobile' and 'shaped by human hands' and ' created continent [...] not on a normal continental plate' 
'immobile' - in reference to what? you seem to have other plates, so they (and their continents) will move ... ? 'shaped by human hands' - so there should be absolutely no erosion, not even inland, or should only the coastline stay intact? 'not normal plate' - how is a continent on a plate not normal? please explain further.

Comment: First, 20,000 years is a time span short enough so that *any* continent will appear to be almost immobile. (On Earth, the distance travelled by a continent in this time span would be around 500 meters, with Australia being the record holder at 1.3 km. People have become able to measure their geographical position with such accuracy only in the 17th century on land and in the 18th century at sea. Before that, the drift over 20,000 years would have been undetectable.) As for the coast line, just avoid anything which could produce marine transgressions and regressions.

Comment: Looks like you want a continent that is not just immobile, but immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tectonic movement can blocked in several ways.

One way is they could stop tectonics. Enough magic could drain the planet of heat. This would stop continents moving. This would stop volcanoes and have other knock on effects, but is an option.

You could also have two continents clashing. This would cause a lot of earthquakes, and lead to an erratic mountain filled border, but it would slow the movement of the continents for the most part. This would mean one edge of the continent would have a lot of erratic stuff happening because two continents are colliding, but it's an option.

## To maintain the coasts you need to counter erosion.

Water, wind, and storms and earthquakes will damage the coasts and change their shape a bit. To stop this, you need maintenance.

One way to do this is with lifeforms. Create intelligent shelled creatures and creatures with hard skeletons like coral. When these creatures die, their shells can reform the coasts in the correct shapes. Careful placement of resources at the chosen edges, culture, and religion could ensure these creatures chose to maintain the shape of the coast.

Of course, war or hunting could change this. You'll need to ensure internal cultures have a strong taboo against intentionally changing the shape of the coastline for pleasure or money, and that invasive species don't damage whatever creatures are maintaining the shape.

Except humans, as you said.

Comment: *"Intelligent shelled creatures"* ? Why not put coral reefs ? It could form a natural anchor and provide coast protection, ref https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/coral_protect.html

Comment: I've added coral reefs to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

**This is a [Frame Challenge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7097/40609)**

First, what to you mean by "don't want... the location... to change naturally"? From the perspective of anyone living on the planet, you could detect a change in longitude, but you can't tell if a change in latitude is occurring (without the use of advanced tectonics knowledge) because there's no point of reference. (We'll ignore the fact that, given enough time, you could figure this out as the other continents are changing longitudinal locations. We'll also ignore the fact that I doubt 20,000 years is enough time to materially detect landmass location changes without the help of satellites.) If all the other land masses move, it will appear that this landmass is moving, too. The only way to guarantee that this landmass *in relation to all other landmasses* never moves is to create an [unobtanium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtainium) anchor that ties every landmass to all other landmasses.

*I assume you want the location to never change because you want people in your story to always find it in the same place. The problem is that all the other landmasses are moving, so it's never going to be in exactly the same place from the perspective of the docks the ship sailed from. In other words, this isn't as valuable as you might think.*

Second, you say you don't want the coastline or "other things" to change. Since coastlines change through erosion, let's assume "other things" includes all forms of erosion. There's only two ways to do that: either there's no water or wind, or the entire continent is built using unobtanium that cannot erode in any way. Of course, this means you can't grow grass, or dig a hole in it, either. This goes against your idea of shaping the continent by human hands — human hands are just another form of erosion.

Finally, and this one's a bit of a nit-pick (but I'll need it for my conclusion), human efforts to change the continent are *just as natural* as any other force that changes the continent. I know it's politically popular today to view humanity as something *not natural,* something that *interferes* with nature rather than being part of nature, but in reality, that simply isn't true. Mother Earth evolved humanity just as She evolved (e.g.) gophers. Humans dig holes in the Earth. Gophers dig holes in the Earth. Sapience simply makes us more proficient at it. (Although anyone who owns a yard infested with gophers may beg to disagree....)

**Conclusion**

As asked, IMO your question can only be answered by asking you to throw away the world-rule that, once created, the continent persists without magic. Your continent requires a sustaining magic to counter erosion and to keep it in place. Magic, being what it is, is capable of discerning between natural human behavior and all other natural behavior.

Worse, I think you need this rule because grass and trees change things. They move the land around. They take from the soil and don't give it back until they die. The very presence, frankly, of any life at all on the continent breaks your "nothing changes" rule. Since I assume you want trees waving in the wind, you're already half-way to what I'm suggesting.

If you are trying (as I suspect) to have the continent be in the same place all the time as people try to reach it, then what you really need is magic that moves the continent to minimize any differences in distance that occur *as the other continents move naturally.* You won't have a perfect solution (without anchoring all the continents as I mentioned before), but I think it would be a cool aspect of the story.

Thus: I believe you need a world rule that describes the creation of the continent with a sustaining magic that allows you to "declare it to be so." In this way your backstory is consistent and you can move forward with the story you actually want to tell.

Comment: Thanks, I definitely agree with the concept that the continent would appear to move via relative position. Although this isn't quite what I'm looking for, thanks for writing such a detailed and developed answer.

Answer (score 2):

Position the continent in a temperate zone that never experiences frost, have it be scrubbed granite, let the shore go into the water at about 60° and continue downwards for at least 300 meters (any loose material will sink and not enhance erosion by the water, and the waves will not hit it full-on). The height of the continent should not exceed the value that would bring it into frosty territory. Ideally no mountains, so we get no fast moving water after rains. No depressions where water might accumulate,

Hey presto, the place will still have that new-continent smell, even after 20 000 years

Comment: I love that newly continent smell!

Answer (score 1):

**There is no plate tectonics on this world.**

You don't need to have your plates scurrying around like Earth does.  Mars is past all that moving plate stuff.  Venus too.  It is all right to have plate tectonics and it is all right to not have it.  You need to live your planetary truth.

Have this be a world with no plate tectonics.  Everything stays put forever.  If this is a fantastic world your readers might not be much concerned with questions of magnetosphere and solar wind.  If you do want those issues you could protect your planet from solar wind in other ways.